# Maximizing the number of Tasks so that starting time of the first Task is always the Earliest

Tags: java, algorithm, priority-queue, greedy

My code is inspired by the following [*article*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/activity-selection-problem-greedy-algo-1/) which contains the code-sample which determines the maximum number of activities that can be performed using a greedy algorithm.

I am treating the problem differently with respect to the greedy idea. I would like to begin at the Earliest Start Time and only then let the greedy algorithm to determine the optimal solution  (i.e. non-overlapping pairs beginning from the Earliest Start Time).

I'm using `PriorityQueue` because I'm treating the input as unsorted.

I'm curious to know how to choose the activity having the Earliest Start Time and proceed with maximum number of non-overlapping pairs (activities)?

*My code:*

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
 
class GFG {
 
  // Pair class
  static class Pair {
 
    int first;
    int second;
 
    Pair(int first, int second)
    {
      this.first = first;
      this.second = second;
    }
  }
 
  static void SelectActivities(int s[], int f[])
  {
 
    // Vector to store results.
    ArrayList<Pair> ans = new ArrayList<>();
 
    // Minimum Priority Queue to sort activities in
    // ascending order of finishing time (f[i]).
    PriorityQueue<Pair> p = new PriorityQueue<>(
      (p1, p2) -> p1.first - p2.first);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      // Pushing elements in priority queue where the
      // key is f[i]
      p.add(new Pair(f[i], s[i]));
    }
 
    Pair it = p.poll();
    int start = it.second;
    int end = it.first;
    ans.add(new Pair(start, end));
 
    while (!p.isEmpty()) {
      Pair itr = p.poll();
      if (itr.second >= end) {
        start = itr.second;
        end = itr.first;
        ans.add(new Pair(start, end));
      }
    }
    System.out.println(
      "Following Activities should be selected. \n");
 
    for (Pair itr : ans) {
      System.out.println(
        "Activity started at: " + itr.first
        + " and ends at  " + itr.second);
    }
  }
 
  // Driver Code
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
 
    int s[] = { 1, 3, 0, 5, 8, 5 };
    int f[] = { 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 9 };
 
    // Function call
    SelectActivities(s, f);
  }
}
```

---

**Current output:**

```
Following Activities should be selected. 

Activity started at: 1 and ends at  2
Activity started at: 3 and ends at  4
Activity started at: 5 and ends at  7
Activity started at: 8 and ends at  9
```

**Desired output:**

```
Following Activities should be selected. 

Activity started at: 0 and ends at  6
Activity started at: 8 and ends at  9
```

Comment: I had a brief look at the link you've provided, seems like it describes the mechanism of greedy algorithms and this sample-problem well. Can you explain the rationale behind your solution? You just want to get more fancy output, or you're treating the problem in a different way? According to the original description, the input data is already sorted by *finish-time*, why do you need a `PriorityQueue`? You're double-sorting the data... or you're treating the input as unsorted?

Comment: I am treating the problem in a different way with respect to the greedy idea. I would like to begin at the Earliest Start Time and let the algorithm determine the greedy solution from such (or non-overlapping pairs beginning from the Earliest Start Time). Yes, the PriorityQueue is there to sort unsorted inputs - if considering other instances for the main method (that may be unsorted).

Comment: OK, that better. So you want a task with the earliest *start time* to be always added and maximize the total number of fulfilled tasks like in the original problem?

Comment: Please add this clarification to the question. And don't use bold font for everything - if you're highlighting everything, it happens that you're highlighting nothing.

Comment: That is correct(: and my apologies I am new and unfamiliar with the platform, I will attempt to clarify better moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to always start with the *earliest task* and then pick the rest tasks in such a way that the number of the fulfilled tasks would be maximal, firstly we need to determine the *earliest task* and then apply a greedy approach to maximize the total number of tasks.

The problem can be addressed in the following steps:

- Parse the pair of given arrays and create a queue of tasks.
- Find the *earliest task* and remove it from the queue.
- Apply a greedy algorithm to find the rest tasks.
- Print the list of tasks.

For conciseness to represent a *task*, I'm using Java 16 record (you can substitute with a class).

That's how it can be implemented:

```
public record Task(int start, int finish) {}

public static void selectActivities(int[] start, int[] finish) {
    if (start.length == 0 || start.length != finish.length) {
        return; // throw an exception
    }
    
    Queue<Task> tasks = createTasks(start, finish);
    Task earliest = pickEarliest(tasks);
    
    List<Task> fulfilledTasks = getFulfilledTasks(tasks, earliest);
    
    printFulfilledTasks(fulfilledTasks);
}

public static Queue<Task> createTasks(int[] start, int[] finish) {
    Queue<Task> tasks = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Task::finish));
    for (int i = 0; i < start.length; i++) {
        tasks.add(new Task(start[i], finish[i]));
    }
    return tasks;
}

public static Task pickEarliest(Queue<Task> tasks) {
    Task earliest = null;
    for (Task task: tasks) {
        if (earliest == null || task.start() < earliest.start()) {
            earliest = task;
        }
    }
    tasks.remove(earliest);
    return earliest;
}

public static List<Task> getFulfilledTasks(Queue<Task> tasks, Task earliest) {
    List<Task> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(earliest);
    
    Task current = earliest;
    
    while (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        Task next = tasks.remove();
        if (next.start() >= current.finish()) {
            result.add(next);
            current = next;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static void printFulfilledTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    selectActivities(new int[]{ 1, 3, 0, 5, 8, 5 }, new int[]{ 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 9 });
}
```

*Output:*

```
Activity has started at: 0 and ended at 6
Activity has started at: 8 and ended at 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it selecting the earliest start time already? Because that is the concept of Greedy. You take the earliest available task with the highest bounty/reward.

Comment: The intention is to start at 0 (earliest start time) and end at 6 then go on from there.

Comment: I see, what you can do is use min() to find the minimum value, then use indexOf() to find its index.

Comment: But one thing, if you start at 0 and end at 6, you will only be able to do 2 activities.

Comment: Compared to 4 in your initial run and Greedy's intention is to squeeze in as many activities as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback(: Yes, you are correct. However, I am keeping the greediness in mind, but would like to begin from the earliest start time - and as you have mentioned when doing so will result in 2 activities.

Comment: Well, you can sort the priority queue based on ascending order of start time.

Comment: ```p.add(new Pair(s[i], f[i]));``` This might work.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately